# C++ Sorting multiple columns in a vector of vectors

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I'm trying to sort multiple columns with my nested vector but I'm unsure on how to actually do it.
I've searched a bunch of posts on here but they only show how to sort up to two columns and I know sorting one column is the following:

```
sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](vector<int> const a, vector<int> const b){return a[0] < b[0];});
```

I have an input where the user enters the size of the vector and it generates accordingly, I want to be able to sort each column on the output.

For example:

Unsorted

```
{3, 7, 2}

{9, 6, 8}

{5, 1, 4}
```

Sorted

```
{3, 1, 2}

{5, 6, 4}

{9, 7, 8}
```

Comment: Maybe a vector of vector is not the suitable structure for you

Comment: @chariked The question is a little bit to broad. Please, provide the code you have so far. It would be much easier to give you a hint if it were clear how you store the data in your application. If vectors are stored row-wise and you want to sort them column-wise then some kind of transpose could be appropriate (i.e. re-organizing the values before sorting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This a classic in linear algebra libraries: the layout of a given matrix can impact a lot the performance due to the patterns of element access.

You face exactly the same outcome. Obviously each vector of int is a row in your case. You need to sort columns. What you can do is the transpose trick:

1. Compute the transpose of your matrix
2. Sort the rows of that transpose
3. Compute back the transpose of this sorted matrix
4. Profit

Some code to illustrate the idea:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> transpose(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const& input) {
    // For simplicity, I assume input is well formed, i.e.:
    //  - All int vectors have the same size
    //  - input is non-empty.
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> tr_input;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < input.front().size(); ++i) {
        std::vector<int> tmp;
        for (auto& vec : input) {
            tmp.push_back(vec.at(i));
        }
        tr_input.push_back(tmp);
    }
    return tr_input;
}
```

Now we have the transpose function, we can implement the algorithm.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> input = { { 3, 7, 2 },
                                        { 9, 6, 8 },
                                        { 5, 1, 4 } };
auto tr = transpose(input);
for (auto& v : tr) {
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
auto sorted = transpose(tr);
```

The result can be viewed on this [<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1696b3eb487c46a)